# Domain connected to wordpress.com and digital ocean droplet (wordpress.org). Two are mixing

Tags: linux, wordpress, dns, digital-ocean

Ok so today I created a domain on GoDaddy, it is for a wordpress site. I created an account on Wordpress.com and connected the domain to it. Afterwards I realized I made a mistake and I infact needed to use Wordpress.org. So I set up a Wordpress Digital Ocean droplet.

I disconnected the domain from the wordpress.com site (via the wordpress dashboard) then used the domain when setting up wordpress on Digital Ocean. When I go to the **Droplet IP**, I get directed to a fresh wp page (which is correct). However when I go to the /wp-admin page, I get sent to an error page which states

```
Something unexpected happened while accessing this website. It looks like it doesn't have an active domain connection upgrade to link the requested domain name to the WordPress.com site.
```

However when I go to the domain, I get directed to the .wordpress.com domain which is what it was *before* I connected my custom one. I'm just so confused!

NOTE - the reason I want to use wordpress on Digital Ocean is due to the fact on Wordpress.com I cannot use custom plugins unless on the business plan.